# How do I create a multiarch deb?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am trying to make a package that will install on Ubuntu 12.04 - 13.* on 1386 and amd64. I've figured out that on the amd64 the only difference is that I need to install the 32 bit libraries. depending on ia32-libs works when the system has it (even though it is overkill) but 13.* does not even have that package. Therefore I am trying to install via the ':i386' extension. When I do `sudo apt-get install blah:i386 ...etc` it works fine.

The following control file yields the message: "Dependency not satisfiable: libgcc1:i386" on 12.04.

```
Package: foo
Version: 1.0-1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Maintainer: bar@gmail.com
Architecture: all
Depends: libgcc1:i386, gcc-4.6-base:i386, libstdc++5:i386, libstdc++6:i386, libsasl2-2:i386, libgstreamermm-0.10-2:i386, libfreetype6:i386,
 libfontconfig1:i386, libX11-6:i386, libXrender1:i386, libice6:i386, libxext6:i386, libsm6:i386
Description: foo is awesome
 Foo is really awesome
Installed-Size: 71140
```

Therefore as per a few other places say, I made the following control file:

```
Package: foo-amd64
Version: 1.0-1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Maintainer: bar@gmail.com
Architecture: amd64
Depends: foo, libgcc1:i386, gcc-4.6-base:i386, libstdc++5:i386, libstdc++6:i386, libsasl2-2:i386, libgstreamermm-0.10-2:i386, libfreetype6:i386,
 libfontconfig1:i386, libX11-6:i386, libXrender1:i386, libice6:i386, libxext6:i386, libsm6:i386
Description: foo is awesome
 Foo is really awesome
Installed-Size: 71140

Package: foo
Version: 1.0-1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Maintainer: bar@gmail.com
Architecture: i386
Depends: gksu
Multi-Arch: foreign
Description: foo is awesome
 Foo is really awesome
Installed-Size: 71140
```

This control file wont even compile as I get the following error message: `dpkg-deb: error: parsing file 'foo/DEBIAN/control' near line 25 package 'foo':
 several package info entries found, only one allowed`. How do I do this correctly?

EDIT: This package does not come with the source. It comes with compiled 32 bit binaries, hence the need to depend on the 32 bit version of the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create separated packages name to get multiarch. Just type:

```
Package: foo-amd64
Version: 1.0-1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Maintainer: bar@gmail.com
Architecture: any
Multi-Arch: same
Depends: foo, libgcc1, gcc-4.6-base, libstdc++5, libstdc++6, libsasl2-2, libgstreamermm-0.10-2, libfreetype6,
 libfontconfig1, libX11-6, libXrender1, libice6, libxext6, libsm6
Description: foo is awesome
 Foo is really awesome
Installed-Size: 71140
```

That should build both, amd64 and i386 packages depending your build environment variable. There are various ways you can convert your packages to multiarch if you use the [recipes instead](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation#Recipes_for_converting_packages):

> ### dh(1) and autotools
>
> The simplest package to convert is one that uses autoconf upstream and
>   dh(1) in the Debian packaging.
>
> 1. Build-depend on debhelper (>= 9).
> 2. Add Pre-Depends: ${misc:Pre-Depends}  to any package listed in debian/control that provides a shared library.
> 3. Update debian/compat to '9'.
> 4. Replace occurrences of `/usr/lib/` in `debian/*.install` with `/usr/lib/*/`.
> 5. If `/usr/lib` (or a subdirectory) is listed as an installation target in `debian/*.install`, or the target of a link in `debian/*.links`,
>      you will need to substitute the value of $(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH) into
>      this file. See `Dynamic debian/* files below.
> 6. Any occurrences of /usr/lib in debian/rules should be replaced with /usr/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH).
> 7. If you needed to use $(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH) in debian/rules in either of the two preceding steps, set DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH in
>      debian/rules by calling: DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH ?= $(shell
>      dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH).
> 8. Once you have built the package and verified that the shared library package contains only the expected files, and that your -dev
>      package still works, mark this shared library package Multi-Arch: same
>      in debian/control.
> 9. Mark the common package(which is "all") Multi-Arch: foreign in debian/control, if it may be needed by the shared library package.
>
> If you have overridden debhelper commands in debian/rules, despite
>   using dh(1) for the rest of the build, you may need to follow the
>   instructions below for classic debhelper to modify mv, cp or rm
>   commands used by your override rules.

There are more examples in the Debian packaging implementation guide https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation. You may also use lithian to make sure your package in completely compliance.

Comment: Ah, the critical difference I forgot to mention is that this package does not come with the source. It comes with compiled 32 bit binaries, hence the need to depend on the 32 bit version of the libraries.

Comment: @chacham15 exactly what package are you trying to install?

Comment: A program that I created (and cannot release source code for).

Comment: Wait, I'm telling you how to *repackage* the binary/sources/whatever. If your program doesn't support amd64 you should only modify the aspects of the packaging as I described.

Comment: No, it supports amd64 but requires those additional dependencies. Those dependencies, however, as stated above fail to be recognized.

Comment: If you have the sources, why not just rebuild the stuff and distribute only the binaries, as God (Debian) says? That you build the package with the buildtools doesn't mean that the source is included in the binary packages.

Comment: The code doesnt compile under 64 bit.

Comment: @chacham15 as I said, there's a link (and I do an ecxerpt) about how to repackage the debian binary. I normally build from sources but I'm sure you can do the same with your package just tweaking the files as shown.

Comment: [Quote](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation#Issues_to_be_aware_of_when_converting): *In Debian 7 (Wheezy), to ensure that (on upgrades from Squeeze) a multiarch-compatible `libc` is configured before
your shared library package is unpacked to the new multiarch library paths (and the old version of the library deleted from `/usr/lib`), each shared library must declare a `Pre-Depends` on the multiarch-support package. This is not needed from Debian 8 (Jessie) onwards, and is now deprecated. Debhelper will automatically fill in the `${misc:Pre-Depends}` variable correctly for you.*